Split alphanumeric string at alphabet character
I have a string, and I would like to split it by alphabet character and keep this character with the right-hand side of the split.
Let say I have this string :
x = '1456p6'

I would like to get the following :
['1456', 'p6']

Using this regex, I was only able to get the following:
re.split('(\d+)', s)
> ['1456', 'p', '6']

I could join the last two parts of the split, but is there a better way to to do it ?

what is the expected behavior on "1a", "1ab", "1ab1", "1a1b"...? Please be a little more precise as to what behavior you desire

You can use a zero width lookahead with your single letter example:
>>> import re 
>>> x = '1456p6'
>>> re.split(r'(?=[a-zA-Z])', x)
['1456', 'p6']

If you want '123abc456' to split into ['123','abc456'] you can use findall:
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|[a-zA-Z]+\d+', '123abc456')
['123', 'abc456']

Or, combine a lookahead and lookbehind to only split at the change between a digit (\d) and a letter:
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z]+\d)', '123abc456')
['123', 'abc456']


Since you need the otherwise "separator" character, maybe usign it to delimit another match, and then using the ol' re.findall can be a simpler way to do it:
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"[[0-9a-zA-Z]?\d+",'1456p6')
['1456', 'p6']

And if there are more digits prefixed by letters in the same string, this will just keep matching:
>>> re.findall(r"[[0-9a-zA-Z]?\d+",'1456p6d65x87y98')
['1456', 'p6', 'd65', 'x87', 'y98']


more_itertools has a function for exactly this sort of thing:
In [24]: import more_itertools

In [25]: x = '1456p6'

In [26]: more_itertools.split_before(x, str.isalpha)
Out[26]: <generator object split_before at 0x10a126580>

In [27]: list(more_itertools.split_before(x, str.isalpha))
Out[27]: [['1', '4', '5', '6'], ['p', '6']]

In [28]: [''.join(s) for s in list(more_itertools.split_before(x, str.isalpha))]
Out[28]: ['1456', 'p6']

Don't forget to pip install more-itertools

x = '1456p6'
for i,y in enumerate(x):
    if y.isalpha():
        idx = i
        break
ls = [x[:idx], x[idx:]]
print(ls)   # Output : ['1456', 'p6']

